Loading data from Azure blob csv file to dataframe
I'm importing data from a SQL table into an Azure Databricks dataframe by exporting it to a CSV file, saving it in Azure Blob Storage, and then loading it into the dataframe. Most records are imported correctly, but for a few, the RecordInsertedDate shows 2023-12-31 in both SQL and the CSV, yet appears as NULL in the dataframe.
Could someone help me understand why this happens? Also, is there a simpler way to import data directly from a SQL table into a dataframe? Here's the code I'm using:
from pyspark.sql.functions import month, year, current_date, col
g5_df1 = spark. read. format ("csv") \
option ("header", "true") \ option ("inferSchema", "true") \load ("dbfs:/mnt/userspace/test/output/a.csv")
g5_df1.createOrReplaceTempView("g5_df1")
gs_df1.display() 

from pyspark.sql.functions import month, year, current_date, col gs_df1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
.option("header", "true") \
.option("inferSchema", "true") \ .load("dbfs:/mnt/userspace/test/output/a.csv")
#gs_df1.createOrReplaceTempView("gs_df1")
gs_df1.display()

Please add the sample records in sql.

the problem is with only single column that too for few records, not with entire record or the entire column. The column value is '2022-12-31 00:00:00.000' in SQL table or csv file. But in the dataframe its showing as null.
from pyspark.sql.functions import month, year, current_date, col
gs_df1 = spark.read.format("csv") 
.option("header", "true") 
.option("inferSchema", "true") 
.load("dbfs:/mnt/userspace/test/output/a.csv")
#gs_df1.createOrReplaceTempView("gs_df1")
gs_df1.display()

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don't add important information on your original question as a comment! Instead edit your question. Please use code formatting markups like ``` to make everything good readable!

You can directly read the data from you SQL tables and Load into dataframe and create temporary table.
I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process
jdbcHostname = "<your SQL SERVER>"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "db02"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};database={jdbcDatabase}"
connectionProperties = {
    "user": "admin02",
    "password": "Welcome@1"
}
dilip_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="SampleTable", properties=connectionProperties)
display(dilip_df)

Results:
ID  Name    RecordInsertedDate
1   Sample Name 1   2023-12-31
2   Sample Name 2   2023-12-31

Creating a temporary view:
dilip_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_sample_table")
result_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM temp_sample_table")
display(result_df)

ID  Name    RecordInsertedDate
1   Sample Name 1   2023-12-31
2   Sample Name 2   2023-12-31

As you mentioned you are seeing NULLs when reading the .CSV file from the ADLS
I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("RecordInsertedDate", StringType(), True)
])
csv_file_path = f"abfss://folder02@<Your STORAGE Account>.dfs.core.windows.net/new02/Query 1 (3).csv"
dilip_df2 = spark.read.csv(csv_file_path, header=True, schema=schema)
dilip_df2 = dilip_df2.withColumn(
    "RecordInsertedDate", 
    F.to_date(F.col("RecordInsertedDate"), "MM/dd/yyyy")  
)
display(dilip_df2)

Results:
ID  Name    RecordInsertedDate
1   Sample Name 1   2023-12-31
2   Sample Name 2   2023-12-31

dilip_df2.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_sample_table2")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM temp_sample_table2").show()

Results:
+---+-------------+------------------+
| ID|         Name|RecordInsertedDate|
+---+-------------+------------------+
|  1|Sample Name 1|        2023-12-31|
|  2|Sample Name 2|        2023-12-31|
+---+-------------+------------------+


In the above code defining the schema for the CSV file
Reading the CSV file with the specified schema and infer date as string temporarily set as StringType to handle parsing
Convert the RecordInsertedDate column to date format after reading the CSV & change the format according to your data

